# Problems with numerical itegration with python

Tags: python, numpy, numerical-integration

I am trying to integrate over values of frequencies (nu's) double integral of the form:

\int_0^1dx{\int}d\gamma\delta^2(x)B(x)n(\gamma)R\left(\frac{\nu}{\gamma^2\delta(x)B(x)}\right)

where delta, B are functions of x that I defined via `def f(x): return f(x)` or so, same with n(gamma), R(...).
My way of calculating that integral for numerous values of nu is using Scipy nquad function:

```
integ = np.array([nquad(lambda g, y: (delta(y,Gamma0,k0,theta)*delta(y,Gamma0,k0,theta)) * (f(y,a,k1,k2,Gamma0,k0)**(3./2.)) * integrandR(n,y,Gamma0,k0,theta,a,k1,k2,g) / (g*g), ranges, opts=[options, options])[0] for n in nu])
```

where nu is numpy array (logspace) of values and rest of the variables under functions are parameters that i set to be usually of order 1 or 10.

This is terribly slow, as calculating even on 20-25 points takes my laptop (8 cores i7 8th gen thinkpad) few minutes and I would need to calculate more or less 200-500 points for many many parameters. Few combinations just took me over 2 days (whole weekend) to complete this way.

I am wondering if I am doing something terribly wrong that my calculations are slow, or is it just the way it is.

B(x), delta(x), n(gamma) are simple rational functions, but R(...) is a combination of Modified Bessel functions of the 2nd kind scipy.kv(n,x), that I take also squared in some cases.

When you look at my code you can see that the "optimizing" step I took was to write squares as x*x instead of x**2 in hopes that it's at least marginally faster.

I also start with calculating on 10-15 points for the first time, so I know I am not wasting that much time.
I can't go on with it for long, since my domain should span ~25 orders of magnitude (in log scale of course).

Comment: Please look at your post after submitting it: Stackoverflow is not https://math.stackexchange.com or https://tex.stackexchange.com, there is no LaTeX support here. You'll have to convert that LaTeX to an image, then use that image with the LaTeX text as caption.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that, unfortunately there's minimal amount of reputation needed to post an image and I do not meet that.

Comment: You can't even use the standard image markdown (i.e. `![caption goes here](http link goes here)`)? (genuinely don't know, I thought 1 rep users could still use normal markdown, even if they don't get to just drop as many images into a post as they want)